# If I wanted opinion-based answers to a naming question, where would I go?

Tags: discussion, questions

It seems like Stack Exchange is geared solely towards fact-based answers. This makes some sense, in that it allows answers to stay relevant, whereas opinions can't be viewed as "right" and can change over time.

I want to be able to ask the same people who help me with programming problems questions for which answers would be considered opinions.  Mainly, sometimes I'll name something, and the name feels wrong, but I can't think of what would be a better name, or why. Where can I have these discussions?

Comment: My gotos are Reddit and Google+. Both work quite well for this.

Answer (score 1):

Chat, assuming that the site's chat room is reasonably active.  SO has many active chat rooms, and Software Engineering's main chat room is active.  If your field is more specialized and there's a Q&A site for the topic, then check its chat room.

You can find a link to chat in the site switcher, near the top.